# Insert geography/Geometry data type into postgres sql

Tags: c#, postgresql, postgis

Have data in CSV file
Parsing the CSV file to insert the data into Postgres DB. One of the column data type is 'geography'

Data is in this form `"0101000020BB100000FCA776FD9E256240F2EBF2AD0F0D43C0"`

```
g = "0101000020BB100000FCA776FD9E256240F2EBF2AD0F0D43C0"
```

Inserting this data with `ST_GeomFromText(@g)`.. But throws this error

> Npgsql.PostgresException : XX000: parse error - invalid geometry Data:
> Severity: ERROR   InvariantSeverity: ERROR   SqlState: XX000
> MessageText: parse error - invalid geometry   Hint: "01" <-- parse
> error at position 2 within geometry   File: lwgeom_pg.c   Line: 58
> Routine: pg_parser_errhint

Code

```
insert into testtable values (@s1,@s2,@s3,@s4,@s5,@s6,@s7,@s8,@s9,@s10,@s11,@s12,@s13,@s14,@s15,@s16,@s17,@s18,@s19,@s20,@s21,@s22,@s23,@s24,@s25,@s26,@s27,ST_GeomFromWKB(@s28))
```

Comment: What you posted looks like binary in hex form, not WKT. Text is `MULTIPOINT ((10 40), (40 30), (20 20), (30 10))`. You'll have to convert that hex string into bytes first, then use ` ST_GeomFromWKB`. Or [use NetTopologySuite with NpgSql](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/nts.html) to send strongly-typed geometry values to the server instead of having the server parse them

Comment: using insert statement .. With c# Npgsql inserting the data

Comment: In any case, post your actual code and table schema. If you used `new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO data (geom) VALUES (@p)", conn)` with a `Point` value you wouldn't have such problems. You wouldn't be able to use `COPY` with `ST_GeomFromText`. Obviously you're doing something else.

Comment: @user3676367 if you used NpgSql with NTS types you wouldn't have such an error. You're trying to parse a hex string as WKT instead of binary

Comment: Add your code to the question itself. Add both the C# and SQL code. The problem here is caused because the *C#* code is sending the hex string instead of a byte array. You could avoid parsing if you used the [WKBReader](https://wsdot-gis.github.io/NetTopologySuiteDoxygen/docs/html/class_net_topology_suite_1_1_i_o_1_1_w_k_b_reader.html#a1886fc18a0c826cb14ad6cc52f7ecbb4) class. Its `HexToBytes` will convert a hex string to `byte[]` and its `Read` method will convert a `byte[]` to an `IGeometry` value that can be used directly as a parameter

Comment: @user3676367 have you tried with `@s28::geography`? Also, can you add how the `INSERT` statement that is sent to the database looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks All, Solved the issue, by casting to geometry then while inserting used the wrapper function "ST_GeomFromWKB"

Answer (score 0):

ST_GeomFromText expects human-readable text, such as 'POINT(145.1756579701904 -38.10204099999818)', as its input.  The text that you have can just be directly inserted into the geometry column with no wrapper function.  Any conversion will be done automatically.

Comment: With no wrapper, I just get the below error                                         
           "Npgsql.PostgresException : 42804: column "location_pt" is of type geography but expression is of type text"